# Schroedinger's label caption update

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code in VBA that goes like this:

```
Sub UserForm2_Activate()
....
If [statement] then  
  Label1.caption = x  
  Label2.caption = x*y  
Else
...
```

When I activate the UserForm with these labels from the other one (using UserForm2.Show) the results are Label1 = x, Label2 = 0. But when I try "UserForm2.Show" from the Immediate window, everything works pretty good and I get the correct data.

What am I doing wrong?

The actual code:

```
If Sheets("SL").Range("B8").Value = True Then
   Label8.Caption = Find_cost(Sheets("SL").Range("b5").Value, Sheets("SL").Range("B4").Value, "ID")
   Label20.Caption = Find_cost(Sheets("SL").Range("b5").Value, Sheets("SL").Range("B4").Value, "ID") * Sheets("SL").Range("b4").Value
Else
   Label8.Caption = "none"
   Label20.Caption = "none"
End If
```

Where "Find_cost" is a custom function

Comment: Put your actual code with value of `x` and `y`.

Comment: When are you calling Show?

Comment: is it `string` type function or `integer` type? May be you need some conversion of `x` and `y`value.

Comment: Where and how are `x` and `y` declared and populated?

Comment: @harun24hr they are all integers. However, the second parameter in the function is 'Long'. I guess I need to check the output of the function

Comment: @JacobH there's a sequence of UserForms. When user inputs presses the "Next" button in the previous UserForm, the UserForm2.Show command is being called

Comment: @jvk That right! check first the `x` and `y` function value.

Comment: @harun24hr the output seems to be allright. Both x and y are integers and they are greater than zero. In fact, the y is an input for the function that returns x

Comment: Looking at your code, the only reason why you might get Label2 = 0 is because y = 0. Is there any chance that the "other form" makes the value in   Sheets("SL").Range("b4") empty - but you don't have this effect when calling the UserForm2 from Immediate window _because_ you are not calling it from the "Other User Form"?

Answer (score 0):

Use a userform_initialize event instead of userform_activate. Also, you should save temporary values in variables and debug with breakpoints.

Comment: thanks. I allready tried using 'initialize' but it didn't work. Gonna use lots of breakpoints apparently